# Setting $variable's content using include()

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to send out a voucher, via the PHP's email() function, where I reference an external .php file using include() as the message contents. Heres the code:

```
$message = '<?php include ("/fullpath/inc/voucher.php"); ?>';
```

This isn't working because I'm declaring it as a text string, but if I don't it will just print out the contents and not put it as the content of the variable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `readfile()` function instead of include.
See: http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

If you want to get the =results= of PHP parsing the voucher.php one way is to make sure that you put voucher.php on a reachable URL, and then call it like:

```
$message = file_get_contents("http://host.domain.com/blabla/voucher.php");
```

This would insert the contents/output of the parsed voucher.php into the variable $message.

If you can't reach the voucher.php publically you have to rewrite it to output the string in the end with the return() function, or write a function in voucher.php that outputs the string you want when called after which you include() it and call the function from within this master PHP script.

Comment: I tried it myself before posting and it worked just fine. The entire contents of the included file ended up in my variable, and then I could process, print, etc. as I wanted? What happens for you?

Comment: Aha, your question is a bit unclear. I see now, based on comments on other replies, that you want the =result= of the voucher.php file and include that one. file_get_contents() should do the trick then or possibly fopen() and to read from it. Good luck!

Comment: Updated a little with more suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [ob_buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) for that, try this:

```
<?php
   ob_start();  // start buffer
   include("file.php");  // read in buffer
   $var=ob_get_contents();  // get buffer content
   ob_end_clean();  // delete buffer content
   echo $var;  // use $var
?>
```

Example from http://www.webmaster-eye.de/include-in-Variable-umleiten.210.artikel.html (German)

Answer (score 3):

*In this post two solutions depending on the circumstances will be described..*

---

#### `voucher.php` is returning a value

If voucher.php has a return statement in it you can safely use `include` to get a hold of this returned value.

See the below example:

**voucher.php**

```
<?php

$contents = "hello world!";

...

return $contents;

?>
```

...

```
$message = include ("/fullpath/inc/voucher.php");
```

---

#### `voucher.php` is printing data that I'd like to store in a variable

If `voucher.php` is printing data that you'd like to store in a variable you can use php's [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) functions to store away the printed data and then assign it to `$message`.

```
ob_start ();
  include ("/fullpath/inc/voucher.php");
  $message = ob_get_contents ();
ob_end   ();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ob_start();
include ("/fullpath/inc/voucher.php");
$message = ob_get_clean();
```

However output buffering in most cases is considered as bad practice and not recommended to use

Like in your case you better have a function declared in `voucher.php` that returns the message as a string. So all the code could be as simple as: `$message = get_voucher();`

Comment: @Ryan Brodie: why wouldn't you copy **exact message error**? These 3 lines are perfectly valid, doubtfully they contain any errors

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same ploblem, here is the functions that resolves the problem for me. It uses the Tobiask answer

```
function call_plugin($target_) { // $target_ is the path to the .PHP file
        ob_start();  // start buffer
        include($target_);  // read in buffer
        $get_content = ob_get_contents();  // get buffer content
        ob_end_clean();
        return $get_content;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = include '/fullpath/inc/voucher.php';
```

and withing `/fullpath/inc/voucher.php`

```
// create $string;
return $string;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$message=file_get_contents("/fullpath/inc/voucher.php");
```

Comment: Which is the "message content" as in the original Question.

Comment: This has worked, but not as expected. The file content's is put into $message but the PHP within voucher.php no longer works? As in it prints the users name using echo $var but this is now unsuccessful?

Comment: As you see from the above comments, I assumed you want to include the text from voucher.php as-is, not its output when interpreted by PHP. You might need eval(file_get_contents("/fullpath/inc/voucher.php")) and inside voucher.php no echo or print, but returning a string.

Comment: A better description of what you assumed in your answer would have probably helped clarify