# Dynamic page title

Tags: php, title

I have a index.php page that is the main page. All pages are included dynamically inside index.php by GET variables.

This is part of the uFlex class.. This will generate the title based on the filename of the file included and i don't like this way..

```
<?php

$page = @$_GET['page'];
$page = !$page ? "home" : $page;
$ext = ".php";
$page_inc = "page/" . str_replace("-", "_", $page) . $ext;
//Page not found
if(!file_exists($page_inc)) send404();
if(!$page_title){
$page_title = ucfirst($page);
}
?>

//   HTML CODE <head>, <title>, ecc
//   And then

<?php include($page_inc); ?>
```

Example: i view `http://sitename.ext/?page=user&id=nickname`

It will include `user.php` and  since includes are made after the `<title>` tag.. i cannot set a title based on a php variable.
Inside `user.php` i have `$user['username']` and i want to set this var as a title..

I need to rewrite a new way to include files with the possibilty to set titles from the file included.

Suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't just accept the input value and include a script with it. Filter or whitelist it. Use `basename()` at least or a regex to constrain it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting $variable's content using include()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725607/setting-variables-content-using-include)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using require, then call functions to generate data.

```
<?php require($page_inc); ?>
<html>
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
....
<div><?php echo $page_content?></div>
```

This is pretty much akin to what wordpress does, albeit a really high level.

Comment: So using this method i need to modify all pages to make `$page_content` contain all the content to be displayed?